# ¿Como hacer el boton atras en android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola amigos, quisiera saber como puedo crear el boton de atras en el ActionBar en android studio, al igual que la imagen, el cual al presionarlo me regrese a la clase anterior. Espero puedan ayudarme y muchas gracias.

Comment: Quieres copiar la función del botón atrás de tu dispositivo, quieres navegar entre fragmentos, o tienes otra cosa en mente?

Comment: Quiero copiar la funcion atras del dispositivo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el manifest para cada activity declaras cual es padre.

```
<application ... >
    ...
    <!-- The main/home activity (it has no parent activity) -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" ...>
        ...
    </activity>
    <!-- A child of the main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
```

android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >

Y para que aparezca el botón, en el onCreate() de los activities tenés que agregar esta lína:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

o

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

si no usas la version de compatibilidad.

Y en los activities hijos para capturar el evento y volver al padre:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Ref: [Providing Up Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) de Android Developers

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo

Comment: De nada. Si te sirvió la respuesta por favor marcale el tílde verde :)

Comment: Ok amigo Muchas gracias